# make div under div with equal width

Tags: html, css

i have these three divs, I added a div with id `m` I need it to go down under the div with  name `wide` having the same width. Thanks for your help.

This is my code.

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
}

#narrow {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  /* Just so it's visible */
  width: 100%;
}

#wide {
  flex: 1;
  /* Grow to rest of container */
  background: lightgreen;
  /* Just so it's visible */
}

#m {}

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
  #wide,
  #narrow {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  #parent {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">Wide (rest of width)</div>
  <div id="narrow">Narrow (200px)</div>
  <div id="m">m</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the calc function to make it the same width as your wide div:

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:100%;
}

#narrow {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  /* Just so it's visible */
}

#wide {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* Grow to rest of container */
  background: lightgreen;
  /* Just so it's visible */
}

#m {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: blue;
}

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
  #wide,
  #narrow,
  #m {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">Wide (rest of width)</div>
  <div id="narrow">Narrow (200px)</div>
  <div id="m">m</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need it to work with my style ,,I don't want to remove anything ...I tried it

Comment: I want that narrow div to stay in its location

Comment: Ok, Sorry, misunderstood your initial question, see edit

Answer (score 1):

If you can use fixed width on `narrow` element you can use `calc()`.

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#narrow {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#wide {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 200px);
  background: lightgreen;
}
#m {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 200px);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">Wide (rest of width)</div>
  <div id="narrow">Narrow (200px)</div>
  <div id="m">m</div>
</div>
```

You can also use **CSS Grid Layout** for this.

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 200px;
}

#narrow {background: lightblue;}
#wide {background: lightgreen}
#m {background: green}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">Wide (rest of width)</div>
  <div id="narrow">Narrow (200px)</div>
  <div id="m">m</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#narrow {
  background: lightblue;
  /* Just so it's visible */
  flex: 1 90%;
}

#wide {
  flex: 1 10%;
  /* Grow to rest of container */
  background: lightgreen;
  /* Just so it's visible */
}

#m {
}

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
  #wide,
  #narrow {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  #parent {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">Wide (rest of width)</div>
  <div id="narrow">Narrow (200px)</div>
  <div id="m">m</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can consider adding some more explanation to this answer instead of just code.